# Cleaner unless validation when checking boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just want to ask if there is a cleaner way to do this validation since `expirable` has a boolean value and I think a method is not needed for it.

```
validates :shelf_life, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 4 },
          allow_nil: true,
          unless: :expirable?

def expirable?
  self.expirable
end
```

I tried it like this

```
  validates :shelf_life, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 4 },
            allow_nil: true,
            unless: self.expirable
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Does this help? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless

Comment: AAAHH it does @ShioT should have looked at the documentation first

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord [automatically adds](https://makandracards.com/makandra/607-automagical-methods-for-boolean-attributes-in-activerecord) `[attribute]?` methods for all boolean attributes.

Considering that, I think you can use your own solution, but without defining your own method:

```
validates :shelf_life, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 4 },
      allow_nil: true,
      unless: :expirable?
```